# Is Kirby a baby in the original "Kirby: Right Back At Ya!"?

Tags: kirby

In the dub version of Kirby: Right Back At Ya!, Kirby is depicted as a baby, who can only communicate by babbling.  Is this true of the original Japanese version as well, or is it a product of the translation?

Comment: I suspect that not even 4kids would completely erase actual dialogue and replace it with babbling, but I have nothing to back that up.

Comment: Is it stated by a character that Kirby is a baby, or are you inferring that from the babbling? From what I recall, Meta-knight referred to Kirby as a star warrior, which doesn't sound like something a baby could be.

Answer (score 2):

The babbling is present in both the English and original Japanese versions.  From skimming the first three episodes, Kirby's dialogue seems roughly the same. Other than the babbling, Kirby is able to repeat some words that others say to him. In the first episode, he is able to repeat the names of Tiff/Fūmu and Tuff/Bun in both the English and Japanese versions. In the third episode, however, Kirby repeats "sword beam" in the Japanese version only. The babbling is most likely not a product of the translation.